# Two functions with different number of type parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This two functions conflicts with each other. 
Is there a workaround for this issue?

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> foo() = ...
inline fun <reified T: Any, reified I: Any> foo() = ...
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I found convenient(at least for me) solution for this issue:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> foo() = foo<T, MyDefaultType>()
inline fun <reified T: Any, reified I: Any> foo(type1: KClass<T> = T::class, type2: KClass<I> = I::class) = ...
```

It can be even concise if you choose to add only one parameter.

Later you can use it like this:

```
val x = foo<A, B>()
val y = foo<C>()
```

That's what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions have identical signatures from the compiler point of view. A type parameter is not part of a signature of a function; it can be inferred by the compiler automatically, and therefore does not serve to disambiguate calls to different overloads.

You need to assign different names to those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation `@JvmName("foo2")` to one of the functions.